# Add a menu resource to a dialog box

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resources

I was wondering if it is possible to add a menu resource to a dialog box. It would be easier to "design" my applications layout in multiple dialog boxes rather than the standard window, however, I will need to be able to add a menu. I would preferably be able to do this through a resource defined menu, however, I have no objections to doing it programmatically.

Right now my application is just starting like this:

```
DialogBox(hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG_UPDATE),NULL,(DLGPROC)updateTitle);
```

in the main function.

Thanks for your help!
Dennis M.

Comment: Can't you just call SetMenu(hDlg, hMenu) during WM_INITDIALOG ?

Comment: @Luke: Fantastic, that worked perfectly! If you set it as answer, I'll best answer you. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Luke: Yes, please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call SetMenu(hDlg, hMenu) during WM_INITDIALOG.

Comment: This solution may require careful placement of the `SetMenu` call: during `WM_INITDIALOG`, the dialog window and its children have already been created. I.e. the dialog will be created and placed without a menu, then you add one, and the client area will be resized accordingly before the dialog becomes visible. If for some reason you are not prepared for resize messages during `WM_INITDIALOG`, this may be a problem.
On the other hand, a menu resource ID in the dialog template header’s menu field will create the dialog with the menu right away.

Answer (score 1):

As Krishty commented on the accepted answer, it is easier and safer to just specify the menu ID in the designer. In the dialog resource properties, scroll down and there is a Menu option. Choose your already created menu from there. You won't see it in the designer, but when you run your app it will be there.